# Filtering by user-agent in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Iis there a way to filter by **user-agent**, in the profile filter (Admin < Profiles < Filter)?

*(Is "Browser version" the same thing as user-agent?)*

Comment: seen this? http://www.blastam.com/blog/index.php/2012/06/block-web-monitoring-bots-in-google-analytics/

Answer (score 2):

Google Analytics Browser Version is NOT the same as the UA header. Browser version will give you `11` or `Edge` or `35` depending on Internet Explorer, Chrome, etc. `Operating System`, `Browser`, `Device Category`, etc. are just Google's pre-parsed User Agent results.

However what you can do is use `Google Tag Manager` and create a custom JavaScript variable that returns `navigator.userAgent` as a variable that you can push to Google Analytics as a custom Dimension.

You can of course do the same without GTM by using pure JavaScript and the `Analytics.js`, GTM is just a much easier way to do these things.

When you have the User Agent as a custom dimension in Google Analytics, you can run reports on these.